# How to disable hibernate formula like filter? Is this possible?

Tags: java, hibernate, formula

In Hibernate ORM we can disable filter using
`session.disableFilter("filterName");`
Is there any solution to disable `formula` in hibernate (with xml mapping configuration)?
I want to disable formula in some circumstances to improve performance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JPA 2.1 you can use function call feature. for this purpose you should move formula query into database function and the call that function in select clause .for example assume that `calculate` is a database function that takes two numeric parameter.
then you can call this function by this way:

```
Object r = em.createQuery("SELECT function('calculate', a.id, 1) FROM Author a WHERE a.id = 1").getSingleResult();
```

and you have to register your custom function by this way:

```
public class MyPostgreSQL9Dialect extends PostgreSQL94Dialect {

    public MyPostgreSQL9Dialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("calculate", new StandardSQLFunction("calculate"));
    }
}
```

for more information check [this](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/database-functions/).